# Threading among elements in css like in publishing software

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

Is there any way to create a layout like this by plain css maybe via flex-box, css-grid or anything except JS:

```
+--------------------------+ +---------------+  
|                          | | sidebar       |  
|                          | | container     |  
|                          | | with border   |  
|                          | | +-----------+ |  
|                          | | |sidebar    | |  
|                          | | |card #1    | |  
|                          | | |           | |  
|                          | | |           | |  
|    main content          | | +-----------+ |  
|    of various            | | +-----------+ |  
|    height                | | |sidebar    | |  
|                          | | |card #2    | |  
|                          | | |           | |  
|                          | | |           | |  
|                          | | +-----------+ |  
|                          | | +-----------+ |  
|                          | | |sidebar    | |  
|                          | | |card #3    | |  
|                          | | |           | |  
|                          | | |           | |  
|                          | | +-----------+ |  
|                          | +---------------+  
|                          | not enough space   
|                          | for one more card  
+--------------------------+                    
+--------------------------------------------+  
|  "sidebar" continues here, with border and |  
|  this header                               |  
|  +-----------+ +-----------++-----------+  |  
|  |sidebar    | |sidebar    ||sidebar    |  |  
|  |card #4    | |card #5    ||card #6    |  |  
|  |           | |           ||           |  |  
|  |           | |           ||           |  |  
|  +-----------+ +-----------++-----------+  |  
|  +-----------+ +-----------+               |  
|  |sidebar    | |sidebar    |               |  
|  |card #7    | |card #n    |               |  
|  |           | |           |               |  
|  |           | |           |               |  
|  +-----------+ +-----------+               |  
|                                            |  
+--------------------------------------------+
```

So cards warping around the main content first from right side, and then from bottom, if main content have various height, whole difficulty that right "real" sidebar, should contain a maximum number of cards, but its height should be less than content container.

Answer (score 0):

I tried making your layout in a simple way, using limited and vanilla CSS. The grid is responsive and I tried to make the names somewhat follow the Bootstrap guidelines.

```css
.col {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.main {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.sidebar .col-12 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main col col-9">
  <div class="col-12">main</div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar col col-3">
  <div class="col col-12">sidebar</div>
  <div class="col col-12">sidebar</div>
  <div class="col col-12">sidebar</div>
</div>

<div class="col col-4">sidebar</div>
<div class="col col-4">sidebar</div>
<div class="col col-4">sidebar</div>

<div class="col col-4">sidebar</div>
<div class="col col-4">sidebar</div>
```

[Working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/amthjpw5/10/)

Comment: Thanks, but whole difficulty that right "real" sidebar, should contain a maximum number of cards, but its height should be less than content container. I updated the question.